# Jquery not considering new div that is added by Jquery + php + jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a php page where I add and delete items from database using Jquery + PHP + AJAX.

Now I am able to delete and add when that page loads for the first time.

Now if I first add an element; which in turn adds record to the DB and then updates the div that contains all the listing of divs.
Example:

```
<div id="all_items">
  <div id= "item_1">
      <a id="delete_link">...</a>
  </div>
  <div id= "item_2">
      <a id="delete_link">...</a>
  </div>
  .... Upto Item n
</div>
```

Now I replace the div with id all_items.

Now I have jQuery at the bottom of the page which calls ajax on a tag of delete_link.

Situtation is:

When page is loaded I can delete any item from the list.
But if I page load i add new item first. (which will update all_items div) after that if I try to click on delete link. Jquery on click selector event is not fired and which in turn doesn't do delete ajax operation.

I couldn't figure out why this is happening.

Looking for some help here.

EDITED:
Sorry for not writing code earliar.
Following is the jQuery I am talking about.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
    jQ(function() {
                jQ("#submit_store").click(function() {
                            var store_name = jQ("#store_name").val();
                            var dataString = 'store_name='+ store_name;
                            dataString += '&mode=insert';
                            if(store_name =='')
                            {
                                        alert("Please Enter store Name");
                            }
                            else {
                                    jQ.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: "<?php echo $mycom_url; ?>/store_insert.php",
                                                data: dataString,
                                                cache: false,
                                                success: function(html){
                                                            jQ("#dvstoreslists").html(html);                                                            
                                                            document.getElementById('store_name').value='';
                                                            document.getElementById('store_name').focus();
                                                }
                                    });
                        }

                        return false;
            });

            jQ(".store_delete").click(function() {
                        var store_id = jQ(this).attr('id');

                        var id = store_id.split("_");
                        var dataString = 'store_id='+ id[2];
                        dataString += '&mode=delete';
                        var to_delete = "#store_list_" + id[2]
                                    jQ.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: "<?php echo $mycom_url; ?>/store_insert.php",
                                                data: dataString,
                                                cache: false,
                                                success: function(html){
                                                            jQ(to_delete).hide("slow");
                                                }
                                    });
                        return false;
            });
});

</script>
```

So If on page load, I delete then delete on click jquery event is fired. But after adding new store and replacing div of stores with new div. then jQuery on click event is not fired.
My HTML is as below.

```
    <div class="sbBox stores">
        <form id="add_storefrm" name="add_storefrm" method="post" action="" >
            <div class="dvAddStore">
                <div class="dvName" id="store_list">
                    <input type="text" id="store_name" name="store_name">
                    <input type="hidden" value="addstore" id="mode" name="mode">        
                </div>

                <div class="btnAddStore">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit_store" value="Add Store" id="submit_store">
               </div>
           </div>
           <div id="dvstoreslists">
               <?php
               $query = "SELECT * FROM #__shoppingstore order by store_id desc;";
               $db->setQuery($query);
               $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
               foreach($rows as $row)
               {
                   echo "<div class=dvlist id=store_list_".$row->store_id ."><div class=dvStoreListLeft>";
                   echo "<div class='slname'><h3>" . $row->store_name . "</h3></div>";
               ?>
               <div class="slDelBtn">
                   <p id = "p_store_<?php echo $row->store_id ; ?>">
                       <a id="store_delete_<?php echo $row->store_id ; ?>" class="store_delete" alt="Delete" onclick="DeleteStore(<?php echo $row->store_id ; ?>);" >            
                       </a>
                   </p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <?php   } ?>
   </div>
   </form>
   </div>
```

Sorry folks for not posting the code earliar.

Comment: we need to see the jquery code if you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you replace the contents of `#all_items` any event handlers that were bound to any descendants will no longer exist. You can use event delegation, using the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, to solve this:

```
$("#all_items").on("click", ".delete_link", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Notice that I'm using a class selector (`.delete_link`) instead of an ID selector for the links. It's invalid to have duplicate IDs in the same document.

Also note that the above will only work if you are using jQuery 1.7 or above. For older versions, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
$("#all_items").on(".delete_link", "click", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

This works because DOM events bubble up the tree from their target. So a click on a link which is a descendant of `#all_items` will bubble up through all of its ancestors and can be captured when it reached `#all_items`.

Answer (score 1):

the `ID` should always be unique so use `class` instead

in your case : `<a id="delete_link">...</a>` to `<a class="delete_link">...</a>`

Comment: sorry for not posting code properly. But I have done the same.

Answer (score 0):

use `live()` instead of `.bind()`

Comment: .on is suggested instead on .live()

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to delete dynamically added delete_link so i think you should use

```
$('id or class').on(click,function(){});
```

Comment: @BillyMoon yes event should be mentioned

Comment: @AmritpalSingh thanks your answer was correct but James answer was before your so I have to select his.